# adding the 'custom' hidden field to simplecart (paypal)

Tags: javascript, simplecart

I would like to send over some custom data to the Paypal Checkout using the 'custom' hidden form field. When not using SimpleCart.js, this is as easy as appending this to the html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="My Custom data">
```

Any idea how I can achieve the same thing with simplecart?

Looking through the source I can see where the form is created/submitted.

```
generateAndSendForm: function (opts) 
{
    var form = simpleCart.$create("form");
    form.attr('style', 'display:none;');
    form.attr('action', opts.action);
    form.attr('method', opts.method);
    simpleCart.each(opts.data, function (val, x, name) 
    {
        form.append(
            simpleCart.$create("input").attr("type","hidden").attr("name",name).val(val)
        );
    });
    simpleCart.$("body").append(form);
    form.el.submit();
    form.remove();
}
```

So, I could just modify this code to make it work, but I'm sure there there must be a better way. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Adding anything extra in simple cart requires adding a simple class...

For example,

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="My Custom data" class="item_customdataname">
```

Notice my class and nomenclature. "item_customdataname".

However, due to the nature of simplecart, I'd reccomend the following;

```
<span style="display: none;" class="item_customdataname">My Custom data</span>
```

Not to say using a hidden input wouldn't work...

E

Comment: The second way with hidden span works, but the first one with hidden input does not - custom data are simply not sent (I'm using SendForm checkout). Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

old thread, but may be interesting for somebody else.
you are looking at the wrong method:

generateAndSendForm:

is used to generate a form that will (most likely) POST data to your backend

what you want to be looking at is:

```
simpleCart.extendCheckout({
  PayPal: function (opts) {
  [...]
```

and you may want to add:

```
if (opts.custom) {
  data.custom = opts.custom;
}
```

somewhere after the equivalent for notifications:

```
if (opts.notify) {
 data.notify_url = opts.notify;
}
```

I have not tested it personally but it should do exactly what you need